# How to join two Polars dataframes based on a condition?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Given the following 3 Polars dataframes

```py
journeys = pl.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'order_id':[11,12,13,14,14,15],'order_type':['restaurant','restaurant','restaurant','restaurant','grocery','grocery']})

restaurant_orders = pl.DataFrame({'id':[11,12,13,14],'item_count':[4,7,3,5]})

grocery_orders = pl.DataFrame({'id':[14,15],'item_count':[23,21]})
```

`journeys`:

[image]

`restaurant_orders`:

[image]

`grocery_orders`:

[image]

I want to bring the `item_count` to the `journeys` dataframe.

The naive way is to filter the `journeys` dataframe based on `order_type` column, perform the join each filtered dataframe and finally concat them back together.

Is there a Polars idiomatic way to perform a conditional (polymorphic?) join to the `journeys` dataframe based on the value of `order_type`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to join on a condition with `polars`.

One way to achieve the desired result is to concatenate the two dataframe to join and add them a column `order_type`.

```
restaurant_orders = restaurant_orders.with_columns(order_type = pl.lit("restaurant"))
grocery_orders = grocery_orders.with_columns(order_type = pl.lit("grocery"))
orders = pl.concat([restaurant_orders, grocery_orders])

journeys.join(orders, left_on=['order_id', 'order_type'], right_on=['id', 'order_type'], how='left')
```

If you have multiple dataframe to concatenate like this, you can use a function to do it based on the name of the DataFrame:

```
def concat_df(list_df: list) -> pl.DataFrame:
  list_newdf = []

  for df in list_df:
    name = [x for x in globals() if globals()[x] is df][0]
    name = name[:-7]

    list_newdf.append(df.with_columns(order_type = pl.lit(name)))
    
  return pl.concat(list_newdf)


list_df = [restaurant_orders, grocery_orders]
orders = concat_df(list_df)

journeys.join(orders, left_on=['order_id', 'order_type'], right_on=['id', 'order_type'], how='left')
```

It will produce the same result. Note that this second solution is dependent of the DataFrame name.

Comment: thanks
I was hoping for a way to use an expression chain of `pl.when().then()` in the `join(right_on=#expression here`

thanks again

Comment: One thing I would do is make the join `how='left'` to ensure you're never accidentally dropping rows.

Comment: Yep thanks for the comment ! I have updated the post.